# How to check if exe file is generating any errors when run?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am generating a exe file through a python script. The script runs fine but when I run exe file, it is not receiving voice input properly. I have used speech_recognition and pyttsx3 modules for voice. Where can I see the errors that are present when I run the exe file?

Comment: you could create a log file using pythons in built logging library https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: Warnings and exceptions should be displayed in the DOS/Terminal window. When debugging, it is often convenient to launch your EXE from a DOS/Terminal window. Print statements also show up in this window and you can temporarily add print statements to your code for debugging.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments are nice but I think what you're missing is that you are creating an executable that runs windowed. If you want to debug, do not supply `--windowed` to pyinstaller when building the executable. Then you will be able to read the print statements, warnings, or errors of your program.

From experience, an issue could be that an important library (e.g. DLL on windows) is missing from the distribution.